# Right alignment error in print()

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing, alignment

I am trying to right align the numerical values which I get from print, but I am getting an error:

```
'float' object has no attribute 'rjust'
```

Here is my code where I am trying to use it at. How should I go about right aligning all the numerical values I get with `print`:

```
enterValue = float(input("The input value is: "))

# We know that the circumference of a circle is 2*pi*r.
CircumferenceV = (2*math.pi*enterValue)
print("The Circumference is : %0.2f" %(circleCircumference.rjust(10)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're applying `rjust` on a **`float`** when it is defined for `str` objects. An alternative is to right align with the `:fill.precision` notation on [`format`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/string.html#format-string-syntax):

```
>>> print("{:10.2f}".format(3.142059))
       3.14
```

Applied on `circleCircumference` :

```
print("The Circumference is : {:10.2f}".format(circleCircumference))
```

Using only `%` one can do the same thing with:

```
>>> circleCircumference = 3.29920
>>> "Circle circumfence: %10.2f" % circleCircumference
'Circle circumfence:        3.30'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you'd only like 2 decimal places, you can use the same answer that [Jim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4952130/jim) suggested but modify it slightly.

```
print("The Circumference is : {:>10.2f}".format(circleCircumference))
```

This tell the print statement to print circleCircumference to 2 places as a float, while right justifying it in a 10 character column.